# Downloading Sentinel-2 images: "offline products" in Copernicus Open Access Hub site

Tags: remote-sensing, satellite

I want to download Sentinel-2 Level1C images for the specific dates. So I tried to download them from Copernicus Open Access Hub site. But I can't download since it says the product is offline,

> Offline product retrieval has been initiated and the product has been moved to Cart. Please check your Cart to know when it will be online.

I'm wondering how to resolve this. Alternatively, I exported and then downloaded satellite images from Google Earth Engine, but the image size is about 135MB unlike Copernicus Open Access Hub's image which is approximately 700MB.

How can I download satellite images? Actually, I'm following a tutorial video which use C2RCC processor in SNAP and in that tutorial each image is about 700MB size and in zip format (just like Copernicus Open Access Hub's image  name and size) So I was wondering how can I acquire such images. And does GEE images applicable for this issue?

Comment: @user2856 Thanks for the help! I just added them to my cart and saw the information. It says: Status: PENDING, Submission Time: 2023-08-17.... And doesn't say anything about when it will be online.

Comment: Then I guess it's a matter of waiting until the retrieved products are online and periodically checking. I'm not sure, but they may send you an email when it's ready.

Comment: When I add them to the cart it can take anywhere between 1 and ~20 hours until they are downloadable. When they are, they will appear like online images in your cart